# Second row of gridbaglayout scrolling out of container

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I am trying to achieve a layout similar to that of a carousel. It needs to have images added horizontally with a checkbox field in the second row. I have a panel within a jscrollpane and individual images are added to the panel as labels. Please see screen shot.

[screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/tox2gvk1z/)
[image]

When I scroll the pane , the first row containing the images stays well within the panel..but if you notice the second row of checkboxes , it scrolls out of the panel. Here is the code ...

```
JLabel lab1=new JLabel();
for (int ii=0; ii<imageFiles.length; ii++) {
       GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();  
        lab1 = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        constraint.gridx = ii;
        constraint.gridy =0;  
        jPanel9.add(lab1,constraint);
    }
    for (int ii=0; ii<imageFiles.length; ii++) {
        GridBagConstraints constraint1 = new GridBagConstraints();         
        constraint1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;           
        chkbox = new Checkbox("asdasdada");
        constraint1.gridx = ii;
        constraint1.gridy =1;

        jPanel9.add(chkbox, constraint1);
      }
```

Not sure what is wrong..Any help is much appreciated..Thanks..

Comment: Your best bet is to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: and this is job for GridLayout(int, int, int, int)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  +1 to that.  Well, metaphorically, since I've run out of votes for the day. -- To create images for the SSCCE, change `ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\images\\"+imageFiles[ii]))` to something like `new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`

Comment: I have made that change.. Is it fine now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing AWT components (heavyweight) with Swing components (lightweight). I have 2 recommendations:

- Don't mix heavyweight and lightweight components
- Try to use lightweight components as much as possible

So in your code, replace `Checkbox` by `JCheckbox` and it should work just fine.